# How to hide three-dots button of chrome video player in version 70+

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, html5-video, shadow-dom

Before this version, the "-internal" pseudo-elements worked fine in CSS. But they deprecated them in the last version, so if I set in my CSS like this:

```
video::-internal-media-controls-overflow-button{
  display: none;
}
```

It works in the previous versions, but the shadow elements of native video player that should changed with that deprecation are still the same. [Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbqvl.png)

The video's shadowroot is closed, so I can not access through JS to delete or hide.

I guess that they should switch those -internal pseudo-elements to -webkit, but currently I am not able to find other solution.

Any idea?

Comment: maybe: hide all controls, then create the custom button you need

Answer (score 3):

> Hello this is the way I solve the issue, in my case I used
>   [blueimp-gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) for a video carousel were video tags are created dynamically by the library, I just added:

```
$('video').each(function (index) {
      $(this).attr("disablepictureinpicture", true);
});
```

> But if you have static video tag just do this:

```
<video width="100%" controls disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload">
```

Original answer you may find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507905/html5-video-player-controls-in-chrome-three-dots-on-the-right-open-blank-scree).