# HTML5 <video> Player Controls in Chrome Three Dots on the Right Open Blank Screen

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I am using a standard HTML5 `<video>` tag to embed a video into page:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="video/intro-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

However, in Chrome's default controls on the right, three dots show up (options), however, when you click on them, it goes to a blank screen and there's no way to get out of it except for refreshing the entire page:

[image]

How do you make the options either go away or prevent a blank screen?

Comment: For me, it isn't doing anything when I click these three dots. Even though I've added `controlsList="fullscreen download remoteplayback"`

Comment: After getting rid of `react-slick` that my video was wrapped in - it started to work as expected.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add `"nodownload" and "noplaybackrate"` in `controlslist` which will hide the download option from the video and add `disablepictureinpicture` inside the video tag which will hide the picture in picture option and by this way the three dots gets hidden:

```
<video width="100%" controls disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload">
</video>
```

Working sample:

```html
<video width="100%" controls disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload noplaybackrate">
  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you add some code as example

Comment: Thank you for this - it worked for audio controls too

Comment: It now has the "playback speed" control

Comment: Also need to add `noplaybackrate` for newer browsers:
```html
<video width="100%" controls disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload noplaybackrate">
```

Answer (score 4):

if you disable the options, using the relevant exclusions from the list below, the dots should disappear:

```
<video controls controlsList="nofullscreen nodownload noremoteplayback noplaybackrate">
</video>
```

See [ControlsList](https://github.com/WICG/controls-list/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) for more details

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears to happen when one of the ancestor elements of the video element has the css style `transform: translate(0,0)` or `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` applied.
Removing it from this element solves the problem with the blank screen.

Comment: This is correct. However, if modifying the ancestor is not possible, is it possible to fix it in the audio/video element?

Comment: No, its not possible to fix it without to modify ancestor elements. This is a bug inside all browsers based on chromium(as i remember), but this is a known issue, and wont be fixed because of specifications

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it! It appears that "Options" button behaves differently based on how video element was embedded in the page. Essentially, it offers, Download or "Picture-in-Picture" features or both, which, if the page is a wide scrollable site with dynamically generated content, caused a blank screen when clicked, which was my issue. Two ways I can solve that problem:

1. Embed video in a separate fixed container (like a modal pop-up)
2. Use a `disablePictureInPicture` attribute to eliminate the Picture-in-Picture feature altogether.  https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/#dom-htmlvideoelement-disablepictureinpicture

Answer (score 0):

To tag on to the other answers, and since it seems undocumented, "noplaybackrate" will hide the playback rate button if it's causing the overflow menu to appear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Note: "disablePictureInPicture" -it should be camelCase only, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It will work if you assign it to `true`:  `autopictureinpicture="true"`, however, Eslint will give an error saying it's an `Unknown property`